# Localising jQuery select/deselect all

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

I'm using the following snippet to create a select/deselect all checkboxes:

http://www.wiseguysonly.com/2010/01/15/select-and-unselect-all-checkboxes-with-jquery/

This is a great help, but just wondering how you might go about localising the effected checkboxes to only those that are siblings (i.e. in the same group of `li` items) of the select/deselect box.

I have multiple lists of checkboxes being generated dynamically (so difficult to give them different selector classes to target with variations of the script) that each have a select/deselect checkbox. Currently, checking one effects the entire group of checkboxes.

(UPDATE)

Sorry, here is some example code -

The HTML -

```
<ul>
    <li class="select-all" ><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"> Select / Deselect All</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 1</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 2</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 3</li>
</ul>

<ul>
    <li class="select-all" ><input type="checkbox" name="select-all" onclick="toggleChecked(this.checked)"> Select / Deselect All</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 1</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 2</li>
    <li><input class="principal-group" type="checkbox" /> 3</li>
</ul>
```

and the Jquery that currently doesn't differentiate between the two groups of siblings -

```
function toggleChecked(status) {
$(".principal-group").each( function() {
$(this).attr("checked",status);
})
}
```

It's phrased differently to your suggestions, as response to a change in status.

Comment: How are your checkboxes grouped? Post some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how your HTML is laid out, but if they're in the same container, you can use

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
   $(this).siblings("input[type=checkbox]").attr("checked", $(this).attr("checked"));
});
```

Here's a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/s2LVZ/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector accordingly. Lets say if your checkboxes are siblings of a li and when you have an event on li and do the select/unselect, here is the way. You have youu add this code in the scope of a sibling element (li in this case)

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().filter('input:checkbox').each( function() {
         $(this).attr("checked",status);
    });
};
```

Where status can be `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've thrown together for my case.  There might be a faster and more efficient method but it gets the job done pretty well and is fairly flexible.

```
$("form#mass-actions-units a#select-all").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var selectAllButton = $(this),
        checkboxes = $('table.view-units tr td input[type="checkbox"]');

    if(selectAllButton.prop("selected")) {
        selectAllButton.prop("selected", false)
                       .text("Select All");
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", false);
        });
    } else {
        selectAllButton.prop("selected", true)
                       .text("Deselect All");
        checkboxes.each(function() {
            $(this).prop("checked", true);
        });
    }
});
```